# Check validation and disable button on click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I have an ASP.NET application and I have implemented the below code to disable users from double clicking and a submit button and thus the method behind the code is not executed than once.

```
OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';" UseSubmitBehavior="false" onclick="BtnSubmit_Click"
```

This was working perfectly, but on one of the pages I had implemented javascript forms validations and the below code is not working:

```
OnClientClick="return validation(); this.disabled = true;"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"  onclick="BtnAdd_Click"
```

The validation is to make sure user does not leave any empty fields, however on clicking the button if validation is success, the button is disabled but the `onclick` method is not being called.

Why exactly is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried calling the validateion function in the form tag on submit event: `<form action="" onSubmit="return validation()">` and keep the onClick as is?

Answer (score 0):

Rikket, you'll have to write separate code to prevent double submission of forms, once its submitted, a Jquery function will help probably, something like below, put this after your JavaScript validation function:

```
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function () {
            var $form = $(this);
            $form.on('submit', function (e) {
                if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    $form.data('submitted', true);
                }
            }).find('input').on('change', function () {
                $form.data('submitted', false);
            });
            return this;
        };
```

And can be called after your validation inside the else :

```
 if (nullFieldTracked == 'true') {
                    alert(nullExceptionMsg);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $('form').preventDoubleSubmission();
                }
```

Comment: its not double submission of forms but rather double submission of the code behind the method. my description might have been a bit misleading. Updated